# Redirect to a new URL without browser issuing a second request?

Tags: http, redirect, webserver, http-status-code-302, http-redirect

Is there a way for a web server to issue a redirect that does not require the browser to issue a second request?

For example, the browser requested `http://www.mysite.com/lion`, but the server wants the browser to change location to `http://www.mysite.com/jungle`.  The only way I know how to accomplish this is for the server to send a `3xx` status code with the `jungle` URL, and the browser issues a new request to retrieve it.

Is it possible for the server to deliver the page `jungle` in response to the `lion` request, and just tell the browser "Set your URL to `http://www.mysite.com/jungle`"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it's called URL rewriting. Both Apache and IIS have modules that allow this.

For Apache, in a .htaccess file or your httpd.conf within a virtual host:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule lion jungle [L]
```

The contents of jungle will be sent when lion is requested, without a redirect.

Comment: But will it cause the browser to change the URL in its address bar?

Comment: No. The URL only changes when the browser is requesting a different URI, which is not happening. You can't both redirect and not redirect. If you want the URL to change (i.e. you want the client, whether it's a browser or search crawler, to know the URI is at another location), you should send the redirect header and appropriate status code, it's the right thing to do. Keep in mind that when you do a redirect, you're only sending headers before the browser makes its second request, it's fast and doesn't waste bandwidth.

Answer (score 1):

In ASP.NET, you can use Server.Transfer(). This causes a different page to be returned for the current request.

Note that the browser has no knowledge this is happening. It would still show `http://www.mysite.com/lion` in the address bar even though you would see the content from `http://www.mysite.com/jungle`.

If you want to inform the browser that a different page is being loaded, then you need a redirect as far as I'm concerned.